# How do I access form data in VB form using classes?

Tags: vb.net, forms, class, oop, error-handling

I have been programming a POS (point of sale) system in VB form using OOP. But every time I try to use for example a textbox from form in one of the classes that I have created, I get an error saying  **"reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference"**. This is the code that I have written for the class 'items' which is basically working out cost of the items in the menu.

```
Public class items
  Public sub new()
    itemcost(0) = Convert.ToDecimal(txtburger.text)
  end sub
end class
```

The error is given under 'txtburger.text' which is part of the form. So I don't know how I'm supposed to access the form directly from the classes.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Also check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to format code.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing some sample code that uses a DataAccess class.

```
Public Class DataAccess
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient

    Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

    Public Function InsertCustomer(Name As String, Address As String) As Integer
        Dim ReturnValue As Integer
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
                cmd As New SqlCommand("Insert Into Customers (CustName, Address) Values (@Name, @Address)", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Name
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Address
            cn.Open()
            ReturnValue = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        End Using
        Return ReturnValue
    End Function

    Public Function GetCustomers() As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
                cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From Customers", cn)
            cn.Open()
            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                dt.Load(reader)
            End Using
        End Using
        Return dt
    End Function

End Class
```

Your form would use the class like this...

```
Private Sub btnAddCustomer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddCustomer.Click
    Dim DA As New DataAccess
    Dim retVal As Integer
    Try
        retVal = DA.InsertCustomer(txtName.Text, txtAddress.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    If retVal > 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Successful Add")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Add failed")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnGetCustomers_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGetCustomers.Click
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim DA As New DataAccess
    Try
        dt = DA.GetCustomers()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

I can't explain the entire thing but you should be able to Google the unfamiliar items.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the value of the burger inside a Parameter.

```
Public class items

  Private _burger as Decimal
  Public sub new(burger_ as Decimal)
    _burger = burger_
    itemcost(0) = Convert.ToDecimal(burger_)
  end sub

end class
```

Then when you call the items class on a form it should look like this.

```
Dim burger as Decimal = txtBurger.text
Dim items as New Items(burger)
```

This is an untested code but the idea is something like that.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best methods to validate information which will be inserted or updated in a database is to use a class instance where properties are annotated which in turn can be validated for issues prior to performing a CRUD operation.

[image]

[Full source](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/windows-forms-csharp/tree/Version1/SqlServerProject) for the following

See the following [project](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/ClassValidationVisualBasic) for validation methods.

For reading in your case a DataTable is okay while passing information for add, edit can be done with a lightweight container (as per code which follows)

- Each method uses named value tuples for returning success, exceptions if any and what was asked for.

**Container**

```
Namespace Classes
    Public Class Employee
        Public Property Id() As Integer
        Public Property ContactTypeIdentifier() As Integer
        Public Property TitleOfCourtesy() As String
        Public Property FirstName() As String
        Public Property LastName() As String
        Public Property HiredDate() As DateTime?
        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return $"{FirstName} {LastName}"
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

**Data operations** for one table

```
Public Class EmployeeOperations

    Private Shared _connectionString As String =
                       "Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=NorthWind2020;Integrated Security=True"

    Public Shared Function Insert(employee As Employee) As (success As Boolean, exception As Exception)

        Using cn = New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = _connectionString}
            Using cmd = New SqlCommand With {.Connection = cn}

                cmd.CommandText =
                    "INSERT INTO dbo.Employees (LastName,FirstName,HireDate)  VALUES (@LastName,@FirstName,@HireDate);" &
                    "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);"

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = employee.FirstName
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = employee.LastName

                If employee.HiredDate.HasValue Then
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@HireDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = employee.HiredDate.Value
                Else
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@HireDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DBNull.Value
                End If

                Try
                    cn.Open()

                    employee.Id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

                    Return (True, Nothing)

                Catch ex As Exception

                    Return (False, ex)

                End Try
            End Using

        End Using
    End Function

    Public Shared Function Read() As (Success As Boolean, Exceptions As Exception, DataTable As DataTable)

        Dim Table As New DataTable

        Try

            Using cn = New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = _connectionString}
                Using cmd = New SqlCommand With {.Connection = cn}

                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName, HireDate FROM dbo.Employees;"
                    cn.Open()
                    Table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())

                End Using

                Return (True, Nothing, Table)

            End Using

        Catch exception As Exception

            Return (False, exception, Nothing)

        End Try
    End Function
    Public Function Remove(identifier As Integer) As (success As Boolean, exception As Exception)
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function
    Public Function Update(employee As Employee) As (success As Boolean, exception As Exception)
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function

End Class
```

**Form code**

```
Public Class Form1
    Private ReadOnly bindingSource As New BindingSource
    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown

        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False

        Dim results = EmployeeOperations.Read()

        If results.Success Then
            bindingSource.DataSource = results.DataTable
            DataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(results.Exceptions.Message)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub AddNewButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddNewButton.Click

        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FirstNameTextBox.Text) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LastNameTextBox.Text) Then
            Dim employee As New Employee With {.FirstName = FirstNameTextBox.Text, .LastName = LastNameTextBox.Text, .HiredDate = DateTimePicker1.Value}
            Dim results = EmployeeOperations.Insert(employee)
            If results.success Then
                Dim table = CType(bindingSource.DataSource, DataTable)
                table.Rows.Add(New Object() {employee.Id, employee.LastName, employee.FirstName, employee.HiredDate})
                MessageBox.Show(employee.Id.ToString())
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(results.exception.Message)
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

**Alternatives**

- Using a `DataAdapter` approach
- Using `Entity Framework 6`, `Entity Framework Core`

Which is best for you is your decision. Personally Entity Framework Core using [Local](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.local?view=efcore-5.0) in tangent with [ToBindingList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.observablecollectionextensions.tobindinglist?view=efcore-5.0) keeps things simple.

To get an idea of ToBindingList with Entity Framework Core see the following C# example (yes I know you are working with VB.NET), just read the readme.md file to get an idea of how this might work for you.

Never worked with Entity Framework Core? There is an NuGet package to `reverse engineer` your database [found here](https://github.com/efcore/EFCore.VisualBasic).

**See also** [Entity Framework Core 3 Windows Forms (VB.NET)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53887.entity-framework-core-3-windows-forms-vb-net.aspx)